# How to change the default registration email ? (plugin and/or non-plugin)

Tags: templates, users, email, user-registration, customization

After a new user registration, WP sends out an email with the login / password, and a link to the login page.

Is there a way to change this defaut email template? I'd also like to change the subject and sender.

Edit : For anyone interested, [here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/welcome-email-editor/) is a plugin solution.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The new user email is sent using the `wp_new_user_notification()` function. This function is pluggable, which means that you can overwrite it:

```
// Redefine user notification function
if ( !function_exists('wp_new_user_notification') ) {
    function wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $plaintext_pass = '' ) {
        $user = new WP_User($user_id);

        $user_login = stripslashes($user->user_login);
        $user_email = stripslashes($user->user_email);

        $message  = sprintf(__('New user registration on your blog %s:'), get_option('blogname')) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user_login) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= sprintf(__('E-mail: %s'), $user_email) . "\r\n";

        @wp_mail(get_option('admin_email'), sprintf(__('[%s] New User Registration'), get_option('blogname')), $message);

        if ( empty($plaintext_pass) )
            return;

        $message  = __('Hi there,') . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= sprintf(__("Welcome to %s! Here's how to log in:"), get_option('blogname')) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= wp_login_url() . "\r\n";
        $message .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user_login) . "\r\n";
        $message .= sprintf(__('Password: %s'), $plaintext_pass) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= sprintf(__('If you have any problems, please contact me at %s.'), get_option('admin_email')) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= __('Adios!');

        wp_mail($user_email, sprintf(__('[%s] Your username and password'), get_option('blogname')), $message);

    }
}
```

**Note:** Overriding pluggable functions cannot be done in the theme functions.php file. WP's pluggable file is already loaded by that point so the function would be defined by WP (i.e. the default). Your custom version must load **before** this happens, which means you must load it in a custom plugin file.

Comment: @Bainternet I cannot seem to get this to work, I have added this to my functions file, but the standard email keeps sending. I'm on multisite, but that shouldn't matter, right?

Comment: OK got it now, it only seems to work as a separate plugin, not when you add it to your `functions.php` file. Now it works perfect, thanks again for that nice piece of code!

Comment: Does it works for multisite too? I can see multisite has bunch of functions inside ms-functions.php for sending notification email.

Comment: Multisite uses `wpmu_signup_user_notification` I think.

Comment: This answer is several years old. The accepted answer doesn't work for me. (Adding it to functions.php has makes no difference to any of the emails sent when a new user registers.) Should I post a new question?

Comment: In the end I found some code that worked for me in this tutorial: http://www.webtipblog.com/change-wordpress-user-registration-welcome-email/

Comment: To address the comments regarding it not working in functions.php, that's because you can't load a custom version of a pluggable function that late. It has nothing to do with the answer being old. You must define your custom function before the WP version is loaded. When loaded in functions.php, the default version of the plugin is already defined. You have to load it *as a plugin* (there's no difference between the answer given and the link Kit posted other than the extra step of loading it as a plugin).

Comment: Doesn't work in 2021, wp 5.6

Answer (score 39):

**For 2018 and onwards users:**

Since WordPress 4.9.0 there are new filters you can use for this (no need for a plugin anymore):

- [wp_new_user_notification_email](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_new_user_notification_email/) - customise email sent to User
- [wp_new_user_notification_email_admin](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_new_user_notification_email_admin/) - customise email sent to Admin

Usage example on email sent to Admin (you can paste this in your theme's **functions.php** ):

```
add_filter( 'wp_new_user_notification_email_admin', 'custom_wp_new_user_notification_email', 10, 3 );

function custom_wp_new_user_notification_email( $wp_new_user_notification_email, $user, $blogname ) {
    $wp_new_user_notification_email['subject'] = sprintf( '[%s] New user %s registered.', $blogname, $user->user_login );
    $wp_new_user_notification_email['message'] = sprintf( "%s ( %s ) has registerd to your blog %s.", $user->user_login, $user->user_email, $blogname );
    return $wp_new_user_notification_email;
}
```

Comment: Alternatively one could use the `wp_new_user_notification_email` and `wp_new_user_notification_email_admin` filters. Those interested can check out the [full documentation and source code](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_new_user_notification/) for `wp_new_user_notification()`.

Comment: Thanks Pete, looks like that was introduced in 4.9.0 and looks like a better solution.

Comment: Hi. I am also using the WP Approve User plugin. 

At the moment it sends the standard email when they sign up. It shouldn’t. It should say that account needs to be approved first. 

We Approve User has option to set the text for when the account has been approved and that is working right. It is the pre approved step before. 

Do I use these new filters you mentioned?

Comment: custom_wp_new_user_notification_email does not change the admin email content for us on wp 5.6

Answer (score 3):

This will not work on functions.php. You need to put this code inside a plugin.

If you don't now to make a plugin for this just use this [link](http://sltaylor.co.uk/blog/customizing-new-user-email-pluggable-function/).

Don't forget to take the update code of this function form [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_new_user_notification).

Comment: Just a point of clarification based on the addition of filter hooks to the `wp_new_user_notification()` function.  This answer specifically references the overriding of `wp_new_user_notification()` as a pluggable function. However, this **does not apply** to using the `wp_new_user_notification_email` and `wp_new_user_notification_email_admin` filters. Those can be used in your functions.php file (or [a site specific plugin](https://wpbitz.com/how-to-create-a-site-specific-plugin/)).