# How can I format email notification after registration?

Tags: notifications, wp-mail, phpmailer

I saw already [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15304/how-to-change-the-default-registration-email-plugin-and-or-non-plugin) answer. And it helped me to make unique mail. It's great. But how to format some text using HTML? For example to work with tags

```
 <b> <i> <font color="red"> <img src="">
```

I wrote

```
spintf("<a href="http://site.com/some-page">Text</a>");
```

And on my mail I got letter with `<a href="http://site.com/some-page">Text</a>` instead of this [Text](http://site.com/some-page).
It seems that WordPress mailer cut HTML, cause I tried printf and echo. Or may be I just do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[wp_mail from Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail)

Use this example:

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );

wp_mail( $mails_to, 'The subject', '<p>The <em>HTML</em> message</p>' );

// Reset content-type to avoid conflicts -- http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23578
remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );

function set_html_content_type() {

    return 'text/html';
}
```