# How can i change email template for new user

Tags: templates, email

When I add a new customer the email goes to new user in this format:

```
From: WordPress [wordpress@siteurl.com]
Subject: [site name] Your user name and password
Message:
         username: user
         Password: password
         siteurl.com/wp-login.php
```

Now I want to change this format Like this:

```
From: My Site Name [info@siteurl.com]
Subject: siteurl.com customer account activated
Message:
       Your customer account has been activated.

       Your Login credentials are:

       Username: user email
       Password: password

       Thanks,
       abcd
```

I tried [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15304/how-to-change-the-default-registration-email-plugin-and-or-non-plugin) but it's not working.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 21):

**For 2018 and onwards users:**

David Gard's answer still works but is old and there's a new better/cleaner way to do this (no need for a plugin anymore).

Since WordPress 4.9.0 there are new filters you can use to customise registration emails:

- [wp_new_user_notification_email](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_new_user_notification_email/) - customise email sent to User
- [wp_new_user_notification_email_admin](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_new_user_notification_email_admin/) - customise email sent to Admin

Usage example on email sent to Admin (you can paste this in your theme's **functions.php** ):

```
add_filter( 'wp_new_user_notification_email_admin', 'custom_wp_new_user_notification_email', 10, 3 );

function custom_wp_new_user_notification_email( $wp_new_user_notification_email, $user, $blogname ) {
    $wp_new_user_notification_email['subject'] = sprintf( '[%s] New user %s registered.', $blogname, $user->user_login );
    $wp_new_user_notification_email['message'] = sprintf( "%s ( %s ) has registerd to your blog %s.", $user->user_login, $user->user_email, $blogname );
    return $wp_new_user_notification_email;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The new user notification email is created and sent by the function `wp_new_user_notification()`, found in **wp-includes/plugable.php**

There is no filter hook within this funciton that will allow you to manipulate the output of the email, however you can of course overwrite any pluggable function via a plugin.

***Note*** - You can only overwrite pluggable functions from within a plugin, not from within your theme.

See here for more details on pluggable functions and a full list of those available - http://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions

This code will create the plugin which will be used instead of the one in **wp-includes/plugable.php** (save it in its own file in **wp-content/plugins/**).

I haven't customised it for you, but this should get you on your way.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Custom new user notification email
 * Description: Overwrites the pluggable 'wp_new_user_notification()' plugin to allow the sending of a custom email
 * Author: David Gard
 * Version: 1.0
 */

if ( !function_exists('wp_new_user_notification') ) :
/**
 * Pluggable - Email login credentials to a newly-registered user
 *
 * A new user registration notification is also sent to admin email.
 *
 * @since 2.0.0
 *
 * @param int    $user_id        User ID.
 * @param string $plaintext_pass Optional. The user's plaintext password. Default empty.
 */
function wp_new_user_notification($user_id, $plaintext_pass = ''){

    $user = get_userdata($user_id);

    // The blogname option is escaped with esc_html on the way into the database in sanitize_option
    // we want to reverse this for the plain text arena of emails.
    $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);

    $message  = sprintf(__('New user registration on your site %s:'), $blogname) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user->user_login) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= sprintf(__('E-mail: %s'), $user->user_email) . "\r\n";

    @wp_mail(get_option('admin_email'), sprintf(__('[%s] New User Registration'), $blogname), $message);

    if ( empty($plaintext_pass) )
        return;

    $message  = sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user->user_login) . "\r\n";
    $message .= sprintf(__('Password: %s'), $plaintext_pass) . "\r\n";
    $message .= wp_login_url() . "\r\n";

    wp_mail($user->user_email, sprintf(__('[%s] Your username and password'), $blogname), $message);

}
endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to a multisite setup, this is configurable through a template that is set up in the database under 2 sections:

**Welcome Email**

and

**Welcome User Email**

http://yoursite/wp-admin/network/settings.php

You can customize it to your liking.