# Without using wordpress cms Is it possible to signup from my html page

Tags: wp-admin, wp-signup

Is there any method to signup to **wordpress** site from my html page.

So that the registered user details must fairly added to database table.

I mean the action must be **similar** to the **process how we generally signup to wordpress cms**.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's what you want, but I got some hints from [*How to display Wordpress User Registration Form in front-end of the website?*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/10309/17305) and [*Quick Tip: Making a Fancy WordPress Register Form from Scratch* from Tutplus](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/quick-tip-making-a-fancy-wordpress-register-form-from-scratch/):

```
<?php
//add this to use wordpress functions outside wordpress
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );        
require('wp-blog-header.php');           
?>

<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div id="register-form">  
        <div class="title">  
            <h1>Register your Account</h1>  
            <span>Sign Up with us and Enjoy!</span>  
        </div>  
            <form action="<?php echo site_url('wp-login.php?action=register', 'login_post') ?>" method="post">  
            <input type="text" name="user_login" value="Username" id="user_login" class="input" />  
            <input type="text" name="user_email" value="E-Mail" id="user_email" class="input"  />  
                <?php do_action('register_form'); ?>  
                <input type="submit" value="Register" id="register" />  
            </form>  
        </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ya this is close to my requirement. But can you tell me what about the other parameters like user_pass,user_status,user_url etc. which are present in wp_user table?.. Also the password is encrypted so we need to apply some mechanism to convert plain text to cyphertext

Comment: You can define the `New User Default Role` at `wp-admin/options-general.php`. For the password encryption, you'll probably need to use a server with `HTTPS`.