# Auto login from custom registration form

Tags: customization, user-registration, wp-login-form

I am trying to login a user from custom user registration form.
My Code for Custom user Register is

```
function register_user($data) {
        $userdata = array(
            'user_login' => $data['email'],
            'user_email' => $data['email'],
            'user_pass' => $data['pssword'],
            'user_nicename' => $data['fname'],
            'display_name' => $data['fname'],
        );
        $usermetedata = array(
            'son_name' => $data['son_name'],
            'shape' => $data['shape'],
            'siret' => $data['siret'],
            'company_email' => $data['company_email'],
            'company_activity' => $data['activity'],
            'staff' => $data['staff'],
            'position_held' => $data['position_held'],
            'company_phone' => $data['company_phone'],
            'company_mobile' => $data['company_mobile'],
            'company_address' => $data['company_address'],
            'company_postal' => $data['company_postal'],
            'company_ville' => $data['company_ville'],
            'url' => $data['url'],
            'personal_region' => $data['personal_region'],
            'personal_address' => $data['personal_address'],
            'personal_ville' => $data['personal_ville'],
            'personal_postal' => $data['personal_postal'],
            'personal_phone' => $data['personal_phone'],
            'personal_mobile' => $data['personal_mobile'],
            'dob' => $data['dob'],
            'invite_email' => $data['invite_email']
        );
        $userid = wp_insert_user($userdata);
        foreach ($usermetedata as $key => $val):
            add_user_meta($userid, $key, $val);
        endforeach;
        gdlr_new_user_registered($userid);
       // echo 'Registration complete. Goto <a href="' . get_site_url() . '/wp-admin">login page</a>.';
        if ($userid) {
            user_activation($userid, $data);

        }

    }
```

And My code for Login currently register user is

```
function gdlr_new_user_registered( $user_id ) {
    $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id ); 
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id, false, is_ssl() );
    $redirect_to = site_url().'le-reseau-social/teepy-tableau-de-bord/';

    do_action( 'wp_login', $user->user_login );
    return $redirect_to;

}
 add_filter('login_redirect', 'gdlr_new_user_registered', 10, 3);
```

But I am not able to login please suggest me or let me know if i am doing some mistake.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For login functionality WordPress provide a function wp_login_form(), It will generate the html for you. Simply change CSS.

For more information see it in [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form)

There is no simple way to register user in wordpress.
Follow the bellow steps.

1. Login into WordPress admin -> Go to settings -> General Settings -> Check Membership Anyone can register -> Select New User Default Role -> Save.
2. show the frontend form - Create a page template and show the form their.
3. save the data on submission - Create another page template to handle frontend form submission. You can also use the same page. While inserting data please take care because you have to insert data in 2 tables, 1 is user and another is user_meta. See wordpress table structure.

I am keeping this answer short and sharing couple of url that will help you in coding.

[How to display WordPress User Registration Form in front end of the website?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10309/how-to-display-wordpress-user-registration-form-in-front-end-of-the-website)

Comment: There is actually api to register users and log them in. Using the default forms or settings is totally not a requirement

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to change in you function as

```
   if ( $user && ! user_can( $user->ID, 'manage_options' ) ) {
    wp_set_current_user( $user->ID, $user_login );
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID );
    do_action( 'wp_login', $user_login );
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use this after registration for autologin.

```
 if ($userid) {
$creds = array(
        'user_login'    => $data['email'],
        'user_password' => $data['pssword'],
        'remember'      => true
    );

    $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
}
```